# How to delete data in database using grid view in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm a beginner in vb.net. Currently I'm develop a simple application by using a grid view. however, I'm facing a problem in deleting the data. When I click delete button, it keep adding the blank line. and this blank line is affected my database also. and this blank line also can't be deleted from database manually.

here my code behind

```
`Imports System.Data.SqlClient
 Imports System.Drawing
 Imports System.Data
 Imports System.Configuration
 Imports System.Linq

 Partial Class test2
 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim AMS As String = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AMS").ConnectionString
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Me.BindData()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BindData()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AMS").ConnectionString
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM ModuleDetail"
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery)
            Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd
            sda.Fill(dt)
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)

    Dim IsDeleted As Boolean = False

    Dim ModuleID As String = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
    Dim ModuleName As Label = CType(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lblModuleName"), Label)
    Dim SubModule As Label = CType(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lblSubModule"), Label)

    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AMS").ConnectionString
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM ModuleDetail WHERE ModuleID=@ModuleID"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleID", ModuleID)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            IsDeleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0
            con.Close()

            GridView1.DataSource = cmd
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using
    If IsDeleted Then
        lblMsg.Text = "'" & SubModule.Text & "' details has been deleted successfully!"
        lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        BindData()
    Else
        lblMsg.Text = "Error while deleting '" & SubModule.Text & "' details"
        lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
```

`

I have try a few code from others sources but it shows the same logic error which keep adding the blank line. I hope you guys can help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Though it might not relevant to your problem context, but I have observed a couple of issues from your code:

1) It seems you are binding grid twice after row delete.

2) Try commenting following lines since you already calling BindData() whithin IsDeleted flag check.

```
GridView1.DataSource = cmd; 
GridView1.DataBind();
```

3) You are assigning the 'Command' object: cmd to the Grid's datasource which is not correct. Check your BindData(...) method how you need to bind Grid actually.